# Bootstrap popover does not work after first page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display images on mouse hover over a button. It works fine on the first page. It opens a small window and shows the image. But on second page it stops working. When I hover over a button it does open a tiny window but there is no image in it.  Let me show you how my .jsp page works.

```
<form:form name="order" modelAttribute="order" method="post" action="/res/confirm">
     <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label> 
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dish</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Images</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${today}" var="menu" varStatus="status">
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:checkbox path="menus" value="${menu}"
                                        label="${menu.name}" /></td>
                                <td>${menu.price}</td>
                                **<td><a href="#" id="popover" class="btn" rel="popover" data-img="resources/img/${menu.name}.jpg">${menu.name}</a></td>**                                  
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>                        
                </table>
            </label>
        </div>                              
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

And this is the javascript I have which is inside the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
            html : true,
            trigger : 'hover',
            placement : 'bottom',               
            content : function() {
                return '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />';
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I think it's worth mentioning here that this menu.jsp page also has other links. This page shows today's menu. Also this page has links to go to other days menus. When I click on any other days menu link, Spring MVC controller method prepares the lists and sends them back to this same menu.jsp page to show menus and other days menu links. To show what I am talking about I have attached a picture here.

[image]

Any help is appreciated and I shall be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

After seeing that you are using `$(this).data('img')` to get the image's URL, the correct way is putting calling `content` by a function like you are already doing.

It seems to me that you should just check the URL in order to see if it's pointing to the real image.

So you should just check the image path.

The way I first proposed is used like this `content :  '<img src="path/to/image.jpg">';`
**[SEE THIS](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=display-image-inside-bootstrap-popover)**

And [**THIS**](http://embed.plnkr.co/nhlFPz)

**ORIGINAL**

I cannot comment so, I'l post this here:

Try using:

```js
content :  '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />';
```

Instead of:

```js
content : function() {
    return '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />';
}
```

Comment: First thanks for trying to answer my question. I tried your code and now I cannot even see the pictures on the first page. I did remove that last colon.

Comment: My friend you are absolutely correct! When I go to second page, the images have different path. On the 1st page I have this path: .../res/resources/img/xyz.jpg. But on the 2nd page I have this path: .../res/**menu**/resources/img/xyz.jpg. Can you please tell me how to change the path so that it always hit ...resources/img/*.jpg and not ..menu/resources/img/*.jpg? Thanks once again

Comment: you know what? I got it! I know how to give it a path that never changes. It's like this: /Context Root/resources/img/pictures.jpg. My Context Root is res. So I gave this path in my jsp: data-img="/res/resources/img/${menu.name}.jpg" Now all the images are loading on every page. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Eduardo Almeida oh thank you too for helping me. I am always here if and when you need me xD now delete these msgs plz xD